ffmpeg how to exclude solid color frames?
I use ffmpeg to make scene mosaic tile with
select=gt(scene\, 0.4),tile=4*10
.
But this picks single color frames.
How do I avoid this?
There's an old discussion about this under this answer's comments.

To avoid boring images such as plain black and white: generate more thumbnails than you need, compress them with jpeg, and choose the images with larger file size. This works surprisingly well by itself to get decent thumbnails.

And here.
-vsync 0 is added which, in this case, tells it to suppress duplication.
